# Difference between Gray-Level and Gray-Scale?

Tags: image-processing, image

What's the difference between the terms Gray-Level & Gray-Scale ?
I think that Gray-Level refers to the matrix of light-intensities of the Black-White digital image itself whilst Gray-Scale refers to a Black-White Image only ( without reference to the matrix )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Grayscale* images measure only the intensity of light, like for images that appear black-and white with monochromatic shades of gray.

*Gray level* refers to the actual level.  e.g.: A pixel might be given a coded gray level of 128 where values range from 0 to 255.

There are terminology analogs to a temperature scale like *Celsius*.  *Grayscale* could be like the word *Celsius* itself that tells you what you are measuring (temperature), but a *gray level* would be analogous to an actual temperature, e.g.: 37°C.